# connect or switch to existing session

Tags: ubuntu, xrdp

I have a htpc running ubuntu connected locally to a TV. I would like to be able to control the stuff displaying to the TV remotely.

So far, I've been able to connect using xrdp (which allows me to control it using windows PCs), but it opens a new, blank desktop session even if I connect using the same user. How can I switch to view and control the existing session that is running on the TV?

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235905/use-xrdp-to-connect-to-desktop-session).

Edit:
Hey Michael Mronzek, thank you for let me know the rules, I will try to follow them with this edit:

You need a vncserver:
 Either you start the vncserver everytime on your own, when you already logged in the remote computer or, the more nicely variant is to start the vncserver when the remote computer starts up. 
Do the following:

```
    sudo apt-get install x11vnc
    sudo x11vnc -storepasswd /etc/x11vnc.pass
```

the password you specify here you need on the xrdp login later. As next, you need a new service for the vncserver to run at start up.

```
    sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

Enter the following into the file

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Start x11vnc at startup.
    After=multi-user.target
    [Service]
    Type=simple
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You need the service to be known by the system:

```
    sudo systemctl enable x11vnc.service
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then change the xrdp.ini
Edit the file `/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`:

```
     ...
     [xrdp1]
     name=Remote Session
     lib=libvnc.so
     username=ask
     password=ask
     ip=127.0.0.1
     port=ask-1

     [xrdp2]
     name=Local Session
     lib=libvnc.so
     username=
     password=ask
     ip=127.0.0.1
     port=5900
     ...
```

Then reboot the remote computer

```
    sudo shutdown -r now
```

The nice thing on this set up is, if you connect from Windows with the standard rdp, you can reboot the computer remotely and connect remotely again, you end up on the normal log on screen of the computer as you would sit in front of it. Choose "Local Session" on the xrdp menu after connecting with rdp. The password is the vncserver passwd. If you just want to open another session, you can go for the "remote session". When you know the port of an existing remote session, you can also join that one, when you enter the port number in the appropriate field.

Have fun and Regards
Highway

Answer (score 0):

There are many options. Here are a few:

- Setup any screen sharing service so that it runs whenever you start up your htpc.
- Use the built in desktop sharing util vino if you use gnome: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/346033
- This project: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/
- Use Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.